# Why does set -e cause my script to exit when it encounters the following?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, set

I have a bash script that checks some log files created by a cron job that have time stamps in the filename (down to the second). It uses the following code:

```
CRON_LOG=$(ls -1 $LOGS_DIR/fetch_cron_{true,false}_$CRON_DATE*.log 2> /dev/null | sed 's/^[^0-9][^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1 &/' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2- | tail -1 )
if [ -f "$CRON_LOG" ]; then
    printf "Checking $CRON_LOG for errors\n"
else
        printf "\n${txtred}Error: cron log for $CRON_NOW does not exist.${txtrst}\n"
        printf "Either the specified date is too old for the log to still be around or there is a problem.\n"
        exit 1
fi
CRIT_ERRS=$(cat $CRON_LOG | grep "ERROR" | grep -v "Duplicate tracking code")
if [ -z "$CRIT_ERRS" ]; then
        printf "%74s[${txtgrn}PASS${txtrst}]\n"
else
        printf "%74s[${txtred}FAIL${txtrst}]\n"
        printf "Critical errors detected! Outputting to console...\n"
        echo $CRIT_ERRS
fi
```

So this bit of code works fine, but I'm trying to clean up my scripts now and implement set -e at the top of all of them. When i do it to this script, it exits with error code 1. Note that I have errors form the first statement dumping to /dev/null. This is because some days the file has the word "true" and other days "false" in it. Anyway, i don't think this is my problem because the script outputs "Checking xxxxx.log for errors." before exiting when I add set -e to the top.

Note: the $CRON_DATE variable is derived form user input. I can run the exact same statement from command line "$./checkcron.sh 01/06/2010" and it works fine without the set -e statement at the top of the script.

UPDATE: I added "set -x" to my script and narrowed the problem down. The last bit of output is:

```
Checking /map/etl/tektronix/logs/fetch_cron_false_010710054501.log for errors
++ cat /map/etl/tektronix/logs/fetch_cron_false_010710054501.log
++ grep ERROR
++ grep -v 'Duplicate tracking code'
+ CRIT_ERRS=

[1]+  Exit 1                  ./checkLoad.sh...
```

So it looks like the problem is occurring on this line:

```
CRIT_ERRS=$(cat $CRON_LOG | grep "ERROR" | grep -v "Duplicate tracking code")
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Parsing the output of ls in a script is generally considered a bad idea, because it does more than you want. In this case, it looks like you want ls to just print out the names of the files matched by the glob, one filename per line, and do nothing else. This can be accomplished with printf:

printf '%s\n' $LOGS_DIR/fetch_cron_{true,false}_$CRON_DATE*.log

This avoids any unpredicted behavior by ls, and also makes the script more portable.

Comment: Also, instead of `cat filename|grep string` you should just do `grep string filename`

Comment: Or `<filename grep string`, if you really want to keep that pipeline-y look.

Comment: @Evan, I will look into getting rid of that ls statement, thanks for the tip. I remember reading that was a bad idea when I first wrote this a few months ago but I didn't have itme to return to it until now. Thanks you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting error *messages* to `/dev/null` does nothing about the *exit status* returned by the script. The reason your `ls` command isn't causing the error is because it's part of a pipeline, and the exit status of the pipeline is the return value of the *last* command in it (unless `pipefail` is enabled).

Given your update, it looks like the command that's failing is the last `grep` in the pipeline. `grep` only returns `0` if it finds a match; otherwise it returns `1`, and if it encounters an error, it returns `2`. This is a danger of `set -e`; things can fail even when you don't expect them to, because commands like `grep` return non-zero status even if there hasn't been an error. It also fails to exit on errors earlier in a pipeline, and so may miss some error.

The solutions given by geocar or ephemient (piping through `cat` or using `|| :` to ensure that the last command in the pipe returns successfully) should help you get around this, if you really want to use `set -e`.

Comment: Thanks Brian, your answer was very helpful. :) I didn't know that set only processed error form the last command in a pipline.

Comment: Using `||:` or `;true` is not a good idea because this hides I/O errors. If there's some reason (resources, etc) that the errors could not be written to output, `cat` will still fail, causing set -e to exit out. Better advice: don't use `set -e`

Answer (score 4):

Adding `set -x`, which prints a trace of the script's execution, may help you diagnose the source of the error.

**Edit:**

Your grep is returning an exit code of 1 since it's not finding the "ERROR" string.

**Edit 2:**

My apologies regarding the colon. I didn't test it.

However, the following works (I tested this one before spouting off) and avoids calling the external `cat`. Because you're setting a variable using the results of a subshell and `set -e` looks at the subshell as a whole, you can do this:

```
CRIT_ERRS=$(cat $CRON_LOG | grep "ERROR" | grep -v "Duplicate tracking code"; true)
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, this helped she more light on the problem. I'm updating my question...

Comment: Extending this... `grep` returns 0 if it finds any matches, and 1 if it finds none.

Comment: Don't get into the habit of using `; true`: it happens to work here, but it generally doesn't help with `set -e`.  Instead, it is more traditional to use `|| :` or `|| true`.

Comment: Haha, thanks! I trie the colon first, worked great, but I noticed that ephemient has about 17,000 more points that Dennis so i'm gonna go ahead and use the double pipes... :)

Comment: Don't use `||:` or `true` because an I/O error (caused by resource exhaustion, for example) won't be detected. If you use `|cat`, it will. If the extra process really bothers you, rewrite the whole line using awk instead of two greps and two cats.

Answer (score 3):

```
bash -c 'f=`false`; echo $?'
1
bash -c 'f=`true`; echo $?'
0
bash -e -c 'f=`false`; echo $?'
bash -e -c 'f=`true`; echo $?'
0
```

Note that backticks (and `$()`) "return" the error code of the last command they run. Solution:

```
CRIT_ERRS=$(cat $CRON_LOG | grep "ERROR" | grep -v "Duplicate tracking code" | cat)
```

Comment: I would use the no-op `:` (colon) here instead of unnecessarily calling an external command: `CRIT_ERRS=$(cat $CRON_LOG | grep "ERROR" | grep -v "Duplicate tracking code" | :)`, but +1 anyway for the cleverness!

Comment: OOPS, never mind, the colon eats stdin and doesn't pass it through!

Comment: You could use `|| :` instead of `| :` to avoid eating stdin; or just use `cat` as geocar suggested

Comment: The traditional method for ignoring failures under `-e` is using `|| :`, i.e. `CRIT_ERRS=$(... || :)`.  @Dennis: don't pipe through `:` and it's fine.

Comment: @ephemient: thanks, I added another way to my answer using `; true` since it's inside a subshell.

Comment: Using `||:` or `;true` will hide errors, which means if there's a resource allocation problem, the result will be an empty string, and the program will continue. Using `|cat` causes `set -e` to still error out in this situation. Better to not use `set -e`, but better still to rewrite this line using `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

Asking for `set -e` makes the script exit as soon as a simple command exits with a non-zero exit status. This combines perniciously with your `ls` command, which exits with a non-zero status when asked to list a non-existent file, which is always the case for you because the `true` and `false` variants don't co-exist.

Comment: Thanks Hyman. I figured it was the ls command at first but it continues to execute the printf statement which occurs after. I also changed that statement so it does not produce an error (I took out teh true part and tested on a day that I knew was false) and the script still exits.

Comment: Just to update on this. Since I'm redirecting errors from that ls statement to /dev/null, I don't believe set picks up on them.

Comment: I don't believe it's the `ls` -- redirection has nothing to do with it, most shells traditionally take the exit status of the last item of a pipeline, and `ls` is the first.